# Evaluation of trigonometric function in C# via IronPython

Tags: c#, python, math, eval, ironpython

I've trying to evaluate some fluid mechanics related expressions using Python Engine from Iron-Python binaries. I've reached the following code:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import math", SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
source.Execute();
source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("2*sin (2)", SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
button1.Text = source.Execute<float>().ToString();
```

Whenever I try to Run, the following error occurs: `Global name 'sin' not defined`.
I also tried `Math.sin()` but with no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: @nneonneo fires an error : Global name 'math' not defined

Comment: That's because you are reassigning the `ScriptSource` and the import is lost. Can you try with `ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import math\r\n2*math.sin(2)", SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);`?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Thanks a lot !! Worked like a charm :) Maybe you could post an answer to get a vote and be easier to discover the solution??

Comment: @Ahmed See @nneonneo's edited answer. The correct way is to store the global state in a `ScriptScope` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `from math import *` instead of `import math` if you want to make all of the math functions accessible in global scope (which may be useful to you since your expressions are mathematical in nature).

You should also create a `ScriptScope` to store the global state, so you can execute multiple statements:

```
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("from math import *", SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
source.Execute(scope);

source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("2*sin (2)", SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
button1.Text = source.Execute<float>(scope).ToString();
```

You can even put objects into the scope from C#:

```
scope.SetVariable("x", 0.577);
```

Comment: I added a note on using scopes to save state.

Comment: A side question, how to implement variables in this form ? For example sin(x) where x is a user input ?

Comment: `scope.SetVariable`. I added it to the answer.